# How to get the excel file name / path in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Say, I'm writing a VBA inside my excel file *sample.xls*. Now I want to get the **full path** of *sample.xls* in my VBA. How do I do it?

Comment: When you say VBScript *inside* sample.xls, do you mean VBA, which is native to Excel?

Comment: Might you want to correct the title and tags then?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you mean VBA, then you can use FullName, for example:

```
strFileFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

(updated as considered by the comments: the former used `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` could more likely be wrong, if other office files may be open(ed) and active. But in case you stored the macro in another file, as mentioned by user @user7296559 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41142956/1915920), and really want the file name of the macro-using file, `ActiveWorkbook` could be the correct choice, if it is guaranteed to be active at execution time.)

Comment: Surely you mean ThisWorkbook.FullName? ;)

Comment: Oorang's comment is right: 'ThisWorkbook.FullName' would be the correct and safe call. Veera's question states: "I'm writing a VBA *inside* my excel file sample.xls. Now I want to get the full path of sample.xls in my VBA". (Emphasis added.) In this case, using 'ThisWorkbook.FullName' is guaranteed to be correct, while 'ActiveWorkbook.FullName' could give a wildly wrong answer if "sample.xls" is not currently the active workbook.

Comment: This works.  Keep in mind that if the file is unsaved, both `ThisWorkbook.Name` and `ThisWorkbook.FullName` will return the file name (e.g. Book1) without a file extension or path.  It might be useful to first [check if the workbook has ever been saved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51530313/5640342).

Answer (score 35):

this is a simple alternative that gives all responses, Fullname, Path, filename.

```
Dim FilePath, FileOnly, PathOnly As String

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))
```

Comment: Insted of `PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))` you can write: 'PathOnly = ThisWorkbook.Path`

Answer (score 8):

```
   strScriptFullname = WScript.ScriptFullName 
   strScriptPath = Left(strScriptFullname, InStrRev(strScriptFullname,"\"))
```

Comment: The op says *inside* sample.xls, which makes me suspicious of VBScript. I suspect VBA.

Answer (score 5):

If you need path only this is the most straightforward way:

```
PathOnly = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Answer (score 5):

if you need path only without file name:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

it would return D:\Folder

if you need file path with file name also:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

it would return D:\Folder\sample.xls

if you need file name only:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

it would return sample.xls

so if you want combine file path and file name to get full directory don't forget to add "" between. otherwise its simpler using .Path

Answer (score 2):

ActiveWorkbook.FullName would be better I think, in case you have the VBA Macro stored in another Excel Workbook, but you want to get the details of the Excel you are editing, not where the Macro resides.

If they reside in the same file, then it does not matter, but if they are in different files, and you want the file where the Data is rather than where the Macro is, then ActiveWorkbook is the one to go for, because it deals with both scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

There is a universal way to get this:

```
Function FileName() As String
    FileName = Mid(Application.Caption, 1, InStrRev(Application.Caption, "-") - 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you say this is a universal way? This does not even answer the question. OP wanted the full name with  the PATH. All your function does is the same as: `ThisWorkbook.Name`

Comment: It is possible to change the [Application.Caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722933/application-caption-behaviour-returning-window-caption-as-well/77720518#77720518) to something else! `Application.Caption = strSomeOtherCaption`