# How to save the file that is being opened?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works for one particular file.

How can I make it work for all my files? Specifically how do I change the name of the file so that it saves the file that is being opened?

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Range("A:A,B:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$A:$A,'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$B:$B")
    ChDir "D:\WayneCSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\WayneCSV\cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    .ChartType = xlLineStacked
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
    "'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$A:$A,'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$B:$B")
End With

ChDir "D:\WayneCSV"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\WayneCSV\" & *YourFileNameHere* &".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Replace the *YourFileNameHere* with the name you'd like to save the file with.

Or if you want to simply save the active workbook with the change

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.FullName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

If you want to loop through all possible workbook or file inside of "D:\WayneCSV" just tell me what you mean by `make it work for all my files?` weather that means open excel sheets, or workbook, or all files with extension of *.xlsx inside of "D:\WayneCSV"

**Edit:**

```
Dim StrFile As String

StrFile = Dir("D:\WayneCSV\*.CSV") ' Looks up each file with CSV extension

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0 ' While the file name is greater then nothing
     Workbooks.Open Filename:= "D:\WayneCSV\" & StrFile ' Open current workbook

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select ' Add a chart
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked ' Add a chart type
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A1:$B1", Range("$A1:$B1").End(xlDown)) ' Set the source range to be the used cells in A:B on the open worksheet 
 With ActiveChart.Parent
     .Height = .Height*1.5 'Increase Height by 50% 
     .Width = .Width*1.5   'Increase Width by 50%
 End With 

'Note the setting of the source will only work while there are no skipped blank if you 
'have empty rows in the source data please tell me and i can provide you with another
' way to get the information 


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\WayneCSV\" & StrFile & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False  ' Save file as excel xlsx with current files name 

ActiveWorkbook.Close ' Close when finished before opening next file this can be removed if you'd like to keep all open for review at the end of loop.

StrFile = Dir ' Next File in Dir
Loop
```

Let me know if it works as I can't test without your folders and data. But it *should* work.

Comment: So I have a bunch of CSV files in D:\WayneCSV. All the csv files have 2 columns (A & B) but different no. of rows. I need to create the same line chart for all of them. Then each file needs to be saved with the same filename except with the regular excel extension.

Comment: You are not specifying how many rows in your ranges.  See my response above for a full answer to your question

Comment: @user2216194 Updated my answer to reflect the request.

Comment: It is giving me an "invalid outside procedure" error. Maybe I am putting my macro in the wrong place...And one other issue that I would like to point out - 'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem' is the name of one file. Each file has a different name.

Comment: I removed 'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem' as that was referring to a Sheet inside of the  file, but i believe all CSV files only have one sheet. So the updated code should take care of both of those issues, Also this macro should be able to run in any location of any workbook, I personally just started a new workbook, went to macros names it cliked Create then pasted this code and ran it.

Comment: @user2140261 - I tried with this line " ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'StrFile'!$A:$B", Range("'StrFile'!$A:$B").End(xlDown)) ' Set the source range to be A:B on worksheet cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem All the way to the end" but it is still not working

Comment: I updated my code all you need to use is `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A:$B", Range("$A:$B").End(xlDown))`

Comment: @user2140261 - Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I was wondering is it possible for me to resize the charts? Like make them 150%.

Comment: Update to include increase the width and height by 50%, and remember if you feel I have the best answer to your question to Accept it as the answer.

Comment: No problem, that's what were all here for. I just hope that in addition to solving this problem I have given you the knowledge and tools to solve similar ones in the future.

Answer (score 0):

where it is written

> Filename:="D:\WayneCSV\cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem.xlsx"

that's your filename you could replace it with ThisWorkbook.FullName it should work

So it should give you something like this.

```
Filename:=ThisWorkbook.FullName,
```

Also I don't understand that part

```
ChDir "D:\WayneCSV"
```

Why put the path then the full name

I'm more an access programmer than an excel one so I could be wrong.

Comment: This would not work as that only changes where it is saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895616/how-to-get-the-excel-file-name-path-in-vba)

I think what you want to do is replace `:="D:\WayneCSV\cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem.xlsx"`
with `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` in `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` line

Answer (score 0):

Your macro, from what I can tell, is adding a chart based off of some data and saving the sheet.

That is a very specialized Macro, but you would need to change the directory as others listed to a directory on your local drive but you also need to find out where the data you are creating a chart for is being stored.

```
Sub Macro1()
' ' Macro1 Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m '  '<<< This is the naming convention and hotkey if you goto Tools > Macros in Excel 2003 or Developer > Macros in 2010

'Range("A:A,B:B").Select      '<<< This is where you are selecting all data in columns A and B and is not needed so I commented it out
'Range("B1").Activate   '<<< This code is 'activating' a cell, but not sure why, so I commented it out as it should not be needed
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select    '<<< You are adding a chart here
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked    '<<<Defining a chart type
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _ "'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$A:$A,'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem'!$B:$B") '<<< Setting it's source data from a worksheet called 'cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem' with header information from Column B and Data from Column A
ChDir "D:\WayneCSV" 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\WayneCSV\cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem.xlsx", _         
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False   '<<< You are saving a copy of your workbook
End Sub
```

To make this work for other workbooks you need to rename all of the ranges to where your data is, rename the tabs to what you have your tabs named, and rename the WorkBook to what you want it saved as and where.

Comment: No need to select the ranges as they are defined in the `Source:=` of `ActiveChart.SetSourceData`

Comment: That is correct, I did not give a better macro I simply updated his macro with comments on what everything was doing so he had a better idea of how to edit it to work with other sheets.  I will update my answer with this.

Comment: I tried with this line " ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'StrFile'!$A:$B", Range("'StrFile'!$A:$B").End(xlDown)) ' Set the source range to be A:B on worksheet cwapp5_MemCPU-Date-Mem All the way to the end" but it is still not working

Comment: Why did you add the .End(xlDown) to the end?  Also if you re-read what I posted you need to say $A:$A and $B:$B not $A:$B because you are setting the data range and headers