# Determine if an Excel workbook has ever been saved?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I tell, using VBA, if an Excel workbook has ever been saved?

I want to know if clicking save will save the document to an existing location or prompt me to choose a save location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Path = vbNullString Then
    'actions if the active workbook hasn't been saved yet go here
Else
    '....
End If
```

Comment: Like this solution, too. - BTW one could consider using `ThisWorkbook.Path` as well (or even a loop through the workbooks collection searching a matching name like "Book1" etc).

Comment: Nice @Jalal !  I just accepted your answer.  It's the simplest solution yet.  I can tell what your code does without an explanation in comments.

Answer (score 8):

I found this helpful.  `.BuiltinDocumentProperties("last save time")` returns a `vbDate` (`VarType` = 7) representing the last time the workbook was saved ONLY IF the file has been saved at least once.  Otherwise it returns a `vbObject` (`VarType` = 9).

```
Function WbSavedAtLeastOnce(ByVal target As Workbook) As Boolean
' Returns TRUE if the target workbook has been saved at least once.

    ' .BuiltinDocumentProperties("last save time") returns a vbDate
    '   only if the file has been saved at least once.
    WbSavedAtLeastOnce = VarType( _
            target.BuiltinDocumentProperties("last save time")) = 7
End Function
```

Use the function like this:

```
Sub Test()
    If WasSavedAtLeastOnce(ActiveWorkbook) Then
        MsgBox "This file has been saved at least once."
    Else
        MsgBox "This file has never been saved."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

The name (e.g. Book1) is a clue although I suppose someon could simply save their workbook with that name.

A clearer check may be as simple as a worksheet function that only works on a saved workbook.

```
'the following returns an empty string if used on an unsaved workbook
=CELL("filename", A1)
```

In VBA the .Address property will return no path when used with the External:=True argument.

```
?range("A1").Address(external:=true)
[Book1]Sheet5!$A$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped!  I meant to post the question with answer at the same time but I didn’t do that. Looks like you posted your answer in between. Seems like this works too although I would give you +1 for the Book1 clue alone ; )

Answer (score 0):

There is another method - *IF* you have programmatic access to the VBA Project (a trust center setting).

(from the debug window)

for each n in thisworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents : ?n.name, n.type, n.saved : next

Look at ThisWorkbook's .saved property value.

false = workbook was never saved.