# is there a way i can copy the first characters of an excel filename and paste it in the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

i want to copy the the first 7 characters of my excel file name into a column in my summary sheet. my file name typically goes  something like "PR_0001_nil_officer.xls". i want to copy the "PR_0001" and paste it in column range G2:G6 of my worksheet. Also Im very new to VBA so which makes this seemingly simple task more complex to me lol

Comment: please note the summary sheet is in the same workbook

Comment: welcome!  Have you tried searching past vba questions?  [This looks like it will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895616/how-to-get-the-excel-file-name-path-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strName As String
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook

        Set wsSummary = .Worksheets("Summary")

        strName = Left(.Name, 7)

        wsSummary.Range("G2:G6").Value = strName

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: @Mayokun, if you feel your question has been answered, than please mark this as such!

Answer (score 2):

- Use `ThisWorkbook.Name` to get the workbook name.
- Use the [Left function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) to get the left 7 characters of that name
- Write it to the range in your desired worksheet

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Summary").Range("G2:G6").Value = Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, 7)
  ```

Comment: and the `$` to return a string value :)

Comment: @JvdV actually yes, but Excel is so dump, that it if the result of `Left$` is actually numeric like `0123456` it will automatically cast the string `Left$("0123456AAAA", 7)` back to a number even if I use `Left$`. So in that case the cell value will be numeric `123456` anyway :( and the `$` has no effect to the cell.

Comment: @Peh, interesting! So would `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Summary").Range("G2:G6").Value = CStr(Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, 7))` work?

Comment: @JvdV obviously not. Excel also casts this string into a number. `.Text` does also not work on a multi cell range so the only solution is `Range("G2:G6").NumberFormat = "@"` before inserting the values. Otherwise numbers as string always automatically cast into numbers.

Comment: @Peh, bummer! I guess in that case one can also resort to the `"'"`tactics. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Summary").Range("G2:G6").Value = "'" & Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, 7)`